# Mail sending issue, asp.net

Tags: asp.net, smtp

Im having issue with mail sending
In web.config file

```
<mailSettings>
    <smtp from="xxxx@companyname.com">
    <network host="mail.authsmtp.com" port="25" userName="xxxx@companyname.com" password="****" defaultCredentials="false"/>
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

I used mail sending code to send mail

but im getting exception as, `The server response was: 5.0.0 Your email system must authenticate before sending mail:XM_ERR:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx(my ip addr)`

Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Thank you

Comment: The answer provided is the solution to this problem. You need to put defaultSettings to true for these settings to work. It should be marked as accepted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to use credentials from *web.config* file?

If yes, than change `defaultSettings` to `true`.

If not, than you must supply valid credentials in code.